# Getting error when calling custom property

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to do a depth first searching algo using vba so i have defined an object called "node" which should contains a "parentNode".

I have tried to define parentNode as collection and use the following

```
Public Property Let Parent(ByRef inputNode As Node)
    Set parentNode = New Collection
    hasParentNode = True
    parentNode.Add inputNode

End Property

Public Property Get Parent() As Node
    Parent = parentNode.Item(1)
End Property
```

But when i call node.Parent i got `Object variable or With block variable not set`

i know that is due to the line "Parent = parentNode.Item(1)" what should be the proper way of doing this? I want it to return the parnetNode assigned by Ref

Thanks

Comment: Show me where parentNode is declared? Its has a value of nothing and that is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Node is an object (I assume, I have no idea what class `Node` actually is), your code is missing the `Set` keyword:

```
Public Property Get Parent() As Node
  Set Parent = parentNode.Item(1) 
End Property
```

Getting `Object variable or With block variable not set` <del>usually</del> sometimes means a missing `Set` keyword.

Comment: @Raymond Try using the `Set` keyword as above and see if that works.